# cant get xpath working on javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey

im trying to do simple xpath with javascript on Grease monkey and it doesnt work for me,:

```
   var xmlString="<body>text<table class='citizens largepadded'><tr><td>bla</td></tr><tr><td>needTHIStext</td></tr></table></body>";
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
    var result = doc.evaluate("//table[@class='citizens largepadded']/tr[2]/td[1]", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    alert(result.stringValue);
```

how do i get text "needTHIStext" find with xpath and alert?

EDIT: thank you for pointing my stupid mistake :) . It works now if anyone wants to do some xpathing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the `FIRST` TD  and not the second one.

```
var xmlString="<body>text<table class='citizens largepadded'><tr><td>bla</td></tr><tr><td>needTHIStext</td></tr></table></body>";
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
    var result = doc.evaluate("//table[@class='citizens largepadded']/tr[2]/td[1]", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    alert(result.stringValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it correct. You need the first `<td>` inside the second `<tr>` so use `/tr[2]/td[1]`:

```
var result = doc.evaluate("//table[@class='citizens largepadded']/tr[2]/td[1]", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```